# Does the total derivative at $(0,0)$ exist: $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does the total derivative of the following function exist at $(0,0)$?

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

---

Edit: Sorry for the confusion! $f(0,0)=0$, and I proved that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. I checked the partial derivatives, they are both $0$ at $(0,0)$. Even more, the derivatives in all the direction are $0$ at $(0,0)$. I proved this by using Taylor expansion of $\sin$. I tried to evualuate:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(h)|}{||h||}$$

By using Taylor expansion, but this didn't work as well. Any other strategies ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Comment: without derivative,i think no,because how can we exclude  zero from denominator?

Comment: hold on a second, how is the function defined at (0,0), if we define it to be say $\pi$ (crossing fingers), $f$ is not even continuous at (0,0), let alone have a deritive

Comment: Is it $\sin(x^2+y^3)$ or $\sin(x^2 y^3)$?

Comment: @Panda It is $\sin(x^2y^3)$, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, $|f(x,y)|\leqslant |y^3|$ because $x^2+(x^2+y^2)^2\geqslant x^2$ and $|\sin(t)|\leqslant |t|$ for every $t$. Hence $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|\leqslant y^2$ for every $|y|\leqslant1$. This alone implies that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with differential $0$ since $|f(h)-f(0,0)|\leqslant\|h\|^2$ for every $h$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\|h\|\leqslant1$.

Comment: Aah thanks ! But I don't understand how you can prove that $|\sin (t) |≤ |t|$ I would say that $|\sin (t)| = |t+R_3(t)| ≤ |t| +C|t|^3 $

Comment: Indeed $|\sin t|\leqslant|t|$ for every real $t$. To see this, either draw the graph of the sine function or note that its derivative (the cosine function) is at most $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: thanks, that is really helpful !